# What is needed to get the text of an SOAP authenticated webpage in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Specifically, what values below are needed to actually get the information from the webpage that I want? It's behind a login page, and using Fiddler on my company's website, I was able to find the full header/cookie/request info of the page I'm trying to get. However, as I am still new, I'm not sure as to exactly what values/syntax is needed to pull the data from the correct webpage with powershell.

I'm able to login to the page using a post invoke-webrequest, but the returned info is from the page you would get on a successful login(welcome to the site yourname), not the info of the url of the page being requested.

The fiddler information on the page that I want to see is:

```
Get /com.fakename.fakename.fakename.fakename.detail.content.EntityDetailsContent.pa?id=17645401423347344&entityType=project HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://fakename.fakename.com/home.pa
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: fakename.fakename.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Cookie:**

```
login=fakeid; 
customerid=1215fakename; 
lang=en;
loginServer=fakeserver; 
ISESSIONID=111111f-2111-1119-911d-21111112f918; 
JSESSIONID=12381681FLINJLIjn79ED; 
notificationLastRun=1533333246
```

The request returned the page with all the information that I wanted. Of course, the real issue is doing it programmatically with powershell. What I've tried so far, has failed. I also tried an httprequest-but I'm unsure about what headers/cookie/syntax to do it is-I tried a solution that only returned the login screen info, it didn't even make it passed that.

```
$username = "fakeid" : $password = "passwordtogetintosite"
$url = "Https://PathtothissiteMainPage.com"
$url2 = "Https://PathofUrlIwant.com/Id=112332323"
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -SessionVariable websession
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.fields['login'] = $username
$form.fields['password'] = $password
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ($url + $form.Action) -WebSession $websession -Method Post -Body $form.Fields
$r2 = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url2 -WebSession $websession
$r2.Content|select-string "id on the page I want"
```

Given the information provided, how/what am I missing to get the command to work for the request of the authenticated url? By the way, the $websession variable holds jsession, login, customerid, but no isession variable that fiddler found-if that helps. Also the pages seem to work with SOAP-if that make it easier.

Comment: Turns out, this question is unanswerable. I am actually missing the WEB API admin credentials for this site, tho I am an admin-the credentials I have are not the same as the site admin(the admin they want can't view the site normally, just an API with commands attached)

Answer (score 0):

I actually asked this same question on Microsoft, and was redirected to my company. turns out the company has a special document I wasn't made aware of, that mentions you need special credentials for the requesting from this site. This user actually cannot view the webpage, only an API of the webpage. With powershell-I found that using this

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "https://domain.site.com/services/WebService?wsdl" -Credentials $superUser
```

The $proxy var gives commands from the schema that I'm able to query the site for, such as $proxy.getRequestFields('ID9191'), which would return all the text fields of request ID9191. So the answer to the question is-if it's a secured https site-go to the site admin and get the rights to run the requests on it, or else good luck hacking the site.